# VSCode folder structure in the side bar

Tags: visual-studio-code

I right clicked on the project name in the side bar and removed it from the side bar. But, now, I can't find a way to add the project folder structure again to the side bar. How can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the folder tree back by right-clicking on the top bar of the explorer and checking "Folders":

[image]

---

Or if you hid that part **entirely** somehow,

use `View` > `Explorer`

or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

---

And for anyone who hid the entire side bar, simply go to `View` > `Appearance` > `Primary side bar`.

Comment: I don't have that option? Is there an extension required for this, or a configuration option that needs to be set?

Comment: View > Appearance > Primary side bar. Only returning the panel but not the explorer. When clicking on Ctrl+Shift+E nothing happens.

Comment: "Folders" is greyed out for me ... ?!

Answer (score 0):

you can get side bar form view (menu)->appearance->show sidebar

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the Ctrl+Shift+E didn't bring the Explorer becuase it was already stacked inside the GutHub menu, so i had to drag it out to the main panel manually.