# VSCode bring back something that was removed from sidebar

Tags: visual-studio-code

I had a bunch of projects open in VSCode and to clean up my left sidebar, I right clicked on them and clicked "Remove from Sidebar"[image]

This removed the folders that I wanted to be removed from my sidebar. When I tried to re-open any of these folders, however, VSCode does nothing. I can open folders that I have not previously removed from the sidebar, but for ones that I have removed, they will not open.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VSC folder structure in the side bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45747749/vsc-folder-structure-in-the-side-bar)

Comment: I'll attach screenshots for simple solution below from Explorer Side Bar. [Hide project from side bar..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M972y.png) [Get it back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkfIZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you right clicked and "hide from side bar" something in visual studio code, you can get it back.

Simply right click the name of the side bar, at the top.  A list of every panel in the side bar is displayed with checkmarks next to it.

Select the one without a checkmark and it comes back.

This also works if you have accidentally hidden the call stack panel from the debug side bar, for example.