# Folder Tree Missing in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm on Windows 10 running VSC 1.15.1

I have one specific project, and **only** one project that is giving me this error. All other projects are fine.

When I open the folder the folder tree is missing from the sidebar. I can see the left/right files that are open. Additionally if I open the terminal in VSC using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> it opens the terminal in the folder as expected.

It seems like the folder is open but the tree is just not displaying as it does when other folders are open.

How to fix this?

[image]

Comment: What happens if you right-click on the "Explorer: open editors" panel and check the "folders" option?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VSC folder structure in the side bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45747749/vsc-folder-structure-in-the-side-bar)

Comment: @wrager That worked.. Thank you. If you write that up as an answer, I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should right-click on the "Explorer: open editors" panel and check the "folders" option.

UPD. This answer is for older VS Code versions, for new ones see the newer answers.

Comment: For me Folders is checked but greyed out and I have no folder tree!

Comment: I had the same problem. Upgrading VS Code from 1.46.1 to 1.62.3 helped.

Comment: This answer does not solve the issue, The answer below actually solves it.

Answer (score 2):

Select "View" -> "Open View..."

A window opens. Select the "Folders" item.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

right-click on the "Explorer: open editors" panel and select "reset locations"